How to add a long list of files to a changelist in Perforce using python's subprocess module and the Helix Core API?
I have 1,000 files that I want to add/move to a single changelist. In other commands such as "add" you can create a list of file paths in a text document and add a "-x" parameter before the file path, creating something like this: p4 -x path/to/text/file/with/paths.txt add.
With "p4 change" however, you have to add your list of files as a field parameter specifically, which as far as I know can't read from an external list: p4 --field "Description={description}" --field "Files=path/to/individual/file.txt" change -o. I can't put them all in a long list since that'd go over the character limit for the command, and inputting each path in to a separate "subprocess.run" command would take a really long time to run through.

The character limit (getconf ARG_MAX) on Linux is about 2 million bytes. So 1,000 files should fit unless the filenames are 2K bytes long.

@samwise is the best one for your question, but another thing to consider is using the official p4python library instead of calling CLI commands with subprocess.  It returns outputs in python lists and dictionaries for easier use and, from my experience, doesn't have issues with maximum characters in a command.

Oh, I must have been doing something wrong then. Last time I tried to create a long list, I got an error because the command was over 1024 characters.

You don't need to use the p4 change command to move all the files to a different changelist.
If you create the change before the files are opened for add in the first place, you can open the files in that changelist directly with the -c flag on the p4 add command:
p4 -x path/to/text/file/with/paths.txt add -c CHANGE

If the files are already opened for add and you want to move them to another changelist, use the p4 reopen command:
p4 -x path/to/text/file/with/paths.txt reopen -c CHANGE

